# Only `require` when Rails server is started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've noticed that ActiveAdmin gets initialized and loaded even when I start up a rake task. Is there any way to specify that all files that ActiveAdmin creates under `app/admin` be loaded *only* when rails server gets booted?

The reason this is so problematic is because when you do something like the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tip do
  filter :score_type, :as => :select, :collection => Tip.all
end
```

And you try to do a `rake db:create`, followed by a `rake db:migrate`, this file loads but Tip doesn't exist yet!

Comment: I typically declare my app/models before creating the app/admin file to manage it. Do you do that flipped?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Nope. But I dropped my db and tried to create/migrate it, and this is what happened

Comment: Would you add the contents of app/models/tip.rb?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott unfortunately I cannot. But I don't see how it's relevant, seeing as I'm just trying to have these files not load for rake tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers your question, but I believe will not solve your true problem.

In Ruby, to tell if a constant is defined:

```
Object.const_defined? "Tip"
 => false 
class Tip; end
> Object.const_defined? "Tip"
 => true
```

So, you could wrap your ActiveAdmin definitions like so:

```
if Object.const_defined? "Tip"
  ActiveAdmin.register Tip do
    filter :score_type, :as => :select, :collection => Tip.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Any way to have this work for all ActiveAdmin resources, rather than having to individually wrap them?

Comment: not without editing the active-admin source. You could delete the directory, run your create, and then bring it back after.